# Google app engine deployment Invalid runtime or the current user is not authorized

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Hi I am getting this error when i try to deploy my app in gae, I have also registered my app in gae .. Please help me.

02:16 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Invalid runtime or the current user is not authorized to use it.
--- end server output ---

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying php? You need to register your user first there:

https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/